# using botov1.8d to work with Amazon MechanicalTurk

Tags: boto, mechanicalturk

I'm new to amazon MTurk, and I'm trying to create hits and fetch results through boto v-1.8d. However, this has brought up a lot of issues and I'm wondering if this is because I'm using an older version of boto.

Note: I can't use the latest release since this is my way of learning how to work with MTurk to implement an open source application called [CrowdForge](https://github.com/borismus/CrowdForge), which is only compatible with boto v1.8d.

If you know of any sample code for 1.8d and/or tutorials, I'd appreciate it if you share the link.

For example: One think im confused about is that the result of the following code is empty brackets "[]" instead of showing a value such as [10000].

```
    #import classes needed from boto library
    from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection

    #specify your own access key and secret access key  
    ACCESS_ID = 'myAccessKey'
    SECRET_KEY = 'mySecretKey'
    HOST = 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'
    SECURE = True

    #make a connection 
    mtc = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_ID,
                          aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY,
                          host = HOST,
                          is_secure = SECURE)

    #display the account balance 
    print mtc.get_account_balance()
```

Comment: As presently written, this question is an off-topic request for off-side resources. You may want to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). More to point, you are probably encountering challenges based on the older version, but it's difficult to know without explicitly inclusion of the code and errors you're encountering.

Comment: You are correct Thomas, my question is more or less vague. The problem is I get general errors like 'Bad Request' or 'Cannot find server' which makes them difficult to pinpoint where the issue rises. My current approach is to write some simple test cases (get account balance, creating a hit, fetching results, reviewing hits) to see whether I can narrow down the problem. I will update the question right now to improve the quality.